# Basic Java Sockets, Server can't send nor clients can recieve anything

Tags: java, sockets

I've written a basic client - server socket program in Java from a tutorial in the book 'java-all-in-one desk reference for Dummies',it contains 3 classes, BartServer,BartClient,BartQuote.. basically what the BartServer.class does is listens for the BartClient.class, the BartClient upon execution will send commands to the BartServer, who will then reply according to what the BartClient sends..

if "get" command, the BartServer will reply a random quote generated from the BartQuote.class
else of "bye" will exit the client...
I tried it on a localhost, the client successfully connects the server, but however the BartServer doesn't do anything nor the clients will recieve... the commands failed to respond or anything... where have I gone wrong? Sorry for my poor English...

```
BartServer:

package socketBart;
import java.net.*;import java.io.*;import java.util.*;

public class BartServer {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int port = 1892;

    BartQuote bart = new BartQuote();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("BartServer 1.0");
        System.out.println("Listening on port "+port);
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket s = ss.accept(); // WAITS for a client to connect, once connected, returns a socket object
        // once clients connects and socket s is created, it will proceed to the next line

        String client;
        client = s.getInetAddress().toString();
        System.out.println("Connected to "+ client);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream()); //READS data sent to this server from CLIENTS
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()); //SENDS data FROM this server to CLIENTS

        out.println("Welcome to BartServer 1.0");// these lines are sent to the client
        out.println("Enter GET to get a quote or BYE to exit.");

        while (true)
        {
            String input = in.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                break;
            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("get"))
            {
                out.println(bart.getQuote());
                System.out.println("Serving "+ client);
            }
            else
                out.println("Huh?");
        }
        out.println("So long suckers!");
        s.close();

        System.out.println("Closed connection to " + client);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

BartClient:

```
package socketBart;
import java.net.*;import java.util.*;import java.io.*;

public class BartClient {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int port = 1892;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Bart Client\n");
    Socket s = getSocket(port);

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Connected on port " + port);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

        //discard welcome message from server
        in.nextLine();

        //discard the exit instructions
        in.nextLine();

        //get a quote
        out.println("get");
        String quote = in.nextLine();

        //disconnect from server
        out.println("bye");
        s.close();

        //write the quote of the 'chalkboard'
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            System.out.println(quote);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static Socket getSocket(int port)
{
    Socket s;
    String host;
    InetAddress ip;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Connect to server: ");
        host = sc.nextLine();

        try
        {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            s = new Socket(ip,port);
            return s;
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("The host is unknown.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Network error, check your port.");
        }//end catch
    }
}

}
```

BartQuote:

```
package socketBart;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BartQuote {

ArrayList<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();

public BartQuote()
{
    q.add("I will not waste chalk");
    q.add("I will not skateboard in the halls");
    q.add("I will not burp in the class");
    q.add("I will not instigate a revolution");
    q.add("It's potato, not potatoe.");
    q.add("I will not encourage others to fly.");
    q.add("Tar is not a plaything.");
    q.add("I will not sell school property.");
    q.add("I will not get very far with this attitude");
    q.add("I will not sell land in Florida.");
    q.add("I will not grease the monkey bars.");
    q.add("I am not a dentist");
    q.add("I will finish what I started.");
    q.add("Hamsters cannot fly");
}

public String getQuote()
{
    int i = new Random().nextInt(q.size());
    return q.get(i);
}



}
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing the PrintWriter after writing the data to it?

Comment: i cud not find anything wrong with ur program, i was stuck sometime in a similar situation... well it sounds stupid but try reversing the order of lines : Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream()); //READS data sent to this server from CLIENTS
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()); //SENDS data FROM this server to CLIENTS................... that is first intialize out and then in on server.

Comment: i did flush after writing the 'get and 'bye' commands in the client...still can't get it to work

Comment: I just copied the code together and flushing did help to get further down the line. Ie I got "Serving /127.0.0.1". So I think making sure both your client and server flush at the right time should fix the problems. Make sure you do the same for the client and you should be fine (that is if your "protocol" works - I didn't go through the logic in detail, but seems easy enough to assume that)

Comment: tried reversing but to no avail...flush before or after? I can't even get the "Welcome to BartServer 1.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line on the server:

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());`

to:

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);`

That will change so that the server always is flushing the stream after a write. Data can otherwise be lingering around in the servers buffer for the output stream.

Note that your client code already is set to auto flush.